# Burninate [rolling]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[rolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rolling) has <del>81</del> 60 questions, no followers, and no wiki.

It is used on questions about topics ranging from [rolling dice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224134/dice-rolling-java-program) to [rolling standard deviations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591423/rolling-standard-deviation-for-every-5th-day-in-r).

Given the wide range of topics, can we burninate this tag?

Comment: They see me... sorry, I can't do it.

Comment: Just transfer the tag and all associated questions to Bicycles.

Comment: Before you burn, it seems that there is a technical use with [r].  So those questions should get retagged before you burn.

Comment: @JasomMArcher It looks like there are only 13 questions tagged with both [tag:rolling] and [tag:r]. I couldn't find anything elsewhere about R and Rolling being particularly related. I believe these questions are just referring to the general concept of a "rolling mean" or other such statistical concepts with a moving window.

Comment: There are also [no questions only tagged "rolling"](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/232959/find-posts-where-x-is-the-only-tag?TargetTagName=rolling).

Comment: I agree that "rolling" does not apply particularly to R.  There are some rolling commands in R, and also in other languages.  Perhaps it just needs a wiki to say what it means.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I went through the questions with the [rolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rolling) tag and removed this tag (together with fixing other problems with the question, if any). This tag is now burninated!

[image: Burninated!]

Comment: Did you replace the tag with anything to indicate that a rolling computation was desired?

Comment: Seems not.  I retagged half of them with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rolling-computation

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I thought that this was not necessary so I didn't retag these. I'm sorry.