# They see me [rolling], they hating

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

Almost [4 years after it was burned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272956/burninate-rolling), [rolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rolling) has now resurfaced and has 181 questions.

Fortunately, this time, it is a bit more specific than the previous case, but it still is very ambiguous.

Most of the questions (I count around 160) are tagged with [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas), and are related calculations applied to rolling windows. For these questions, there already is [rolling-computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rolling-computation). I also discovered two other smaller tags, [rolling-average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rolling-average) and [rolling-sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rolling-sum), which I think must be synonymized to [rolling-computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rolling-computation), as they seem to be subsets of it. (I might be wrong, though).

Most of the [remaining questions, i.e, the ones without the R or the Pandas tags](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brolling%5D+-%5Br%5D+-%5Bpandas%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0), are also related to rolling window computations. At the end of the disambiguation, we can probably add [rolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rolling) as a synonym for [rolling-computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rolling-computation), which should probably help prevent the re-creation of this tag.

Apart from that there seem to be some questions related to:

- Rolling dice, for which [dice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dice) is sufficient. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764747/rolling-2-dice-in-python-and-if-they-are-the-same-number-roll-again-and-continu)).
- Rolling log appenders, for which that particular logger's tag is sufficient ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343518/serilog-rolling-log-file-per-day-but-also-per-application-run)).
- Rolling deployment. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48005265/ansible-ssh-error-node-getting-scaled-down-behind-aws-elb-before-code-is-dep)).

Given these many confusing meanings for the tag, and the fact that it has already been burned, I request for the tag to be disambiguated, and the questions be tagged with much more relevant tags.

Comment: [rolling + r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rolling+r) is not rolling anymore.

Comment: There were 18 non python ones left, (after r was cleaned). I retagged them to better tags.

Comment: All pandas questions have been disambiguated.

Comment: Once the [pandas] were cleaned, there were around 7 python related ones left, which I retagged/closed.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be highly correlated to naming conventions in Python and R whereby packages have began using non standard verbiage surrounding the word "rolling".

In the rest of the field, these approaches are well defined, albeit under different names than "rolling-calculation", "rolling-average", etc.

The term for examining a subset of items from a whole set is generally referred to as a [sliding-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sliding-window).

There are various terms for calculating values as subset of whole sets as well. For example, the [moving-average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moving-average).

The number of packages and functions relating to "rolling" seems to be growing, and also "rolling" is an actual name of a function for DataFrames in panda: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html. Here is a question which properly references the rolling function: [pandas rolling() function with monthly offset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50702986/1026459)

I do not believe that it would cause any less ambiguity to synonymize "rolling" to "rolling-computation". If anything, it should be a synonym of "sliding-window". It could also be argued it should be "rolling-window", following convention. By relation, this could also expand to the tag "sliding", which seems to be in the same situation.

Given the vagueness of solutions to this issue, and the fact that the term "rolling" itself is gaining prominence in use, it should probably just be left in place at this point.

Comment: I'm fine with just a cleanup of [tag:rolling] and leaving it. However, your answer at the start clearly mentions that sliding window and moving average is the correct term, which implies that synonymizing [rolling-*] to those tags makes more sense than leaving it alone. Also, pandas dataframe has quite a lot of functions apart from rolling, which creates the argument about creating tags for those. (Also note that, I didn't ask a burn-req this time, I asked for tag-disambiguation, because the tag certainly is being used for various on topic uses).